# ¿Se pueden buscar hilos?

Tags: soporte

Quiero saber si se pueden buscar hilos por su titulo por parte de otros usuarios.

Comment: Buenas Amaretto. ¿Puedes explicar mejor qué quieres buscar?  Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento de SOes y Meta. Un saludo